# JMeter: Users are decreasing for subsequent http requests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a scenario where I need to login with 100 users and all 100 users landed safely on welcome page. Out of 100, 80 users clicked on link1 and landed on link1 page. Out of 80 uses, 50 users clicked on link2 from link1 page and landed on link2 page.

Would this possible with JMeter?
Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is your plan for "remaining" users you can choose one of the below approaches:

1. Distribution of user load between requests (one group of users is executing one sampler (or group of samplers) requests and another group of users is doing something else. It can be done using following test elements:

   - [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
   - [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
   - [Weighted Switch Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/)

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) for more information on the above approaches.

2. One group of users is doing something, another is being shut down. In this case example Test Plan configuration will look like:

   - Login Request
   - [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) (condition `${__threadNum} <= 80`)

     - Link 1
     - If Controller (condition `${__threadNum} <= 50`)

       - Link 2

   [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) is a function which basically returns current virtual user number so after first If Controller 80 virtual users will continue, and after second one only 50 will be left. Others either will go to the next loop iteration or will be shut down (depending on your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings)